# How to update the value of all empty columns with the click of a jbutton, leaving the other data in a table unchanged in java?

Tags: java, mysql, null

I want to fill up `null` columns in my `MySQlL` database.

I have a table named `issuebook` where are 6 fields and last two fields are null.

Image is given below:

[image]

I want that, when I click the `jbutton` the null fields will be updated and insert values in all the `null` columns of every row.

I wish there would be no change in the value of all the rows. Just fill the `null` columns with new values.
But when I click the `jbutton` The value of each row becomes the same.

Image is given below(when i click `jbutton`):

[image]

My code of `jbutton` is given below:

```
        btnIssue = new JButton("ISSUE");
        btnIssue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            DateTimeFormatter dfd=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
            LocalDateTime returnvalue  = now.plusDays(30);
            DefaultTableModel d= (DefaultTableModel) bookRecord.getModel();
            
            try {
                for(int i = 0; i < d.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    id = d.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
                    member = d.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
                    book = d.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
                    rqst = d.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
                    
                    pst = con.prepareStatement("update issuebook set ID = ?, MemberName = ?, BookName = ?, RequestTime = ?, IssueDate = ?, ReturnDate = ? where IssueDate is null and ReturnDate is null");
                    pst.setString(1, id);
                    pst.setString(2, member);
                    pst.setString(3, book);
                    pst.setString(4, rqst);
                    pst.setString(5, dfd.format(now));
                    pst.setString(6, dfd.format(returnvalue));
                    pst.executeUpdate();
                }
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Book Issued Successfully!");
                issueLoad();
                d.setRowCount(0);
            }
            catch(SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to update the other fields then it's simple - just don't set them. If they are not included in the `UPDATE` statement then they won't be modified.

e.g.

```
update issuebook set IssueDate = ?, ReturnDate = ? where IssueDate is null and ReturnDate is null
```

And, if, as it appears, you're going to set all rows to have the same dates (now, and now+30 days) then you can just execute the query once. You don't need to fetch the existing data at all.

It's a long time since I've done any Java in anger but I'm pretty sure you can simplify all that code down to:

```
btnIssue = new JButton("ISSUE");

btnIssue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    DateTimeFormatter dfd = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime returnvalue  = now.plusDays(30);

    try {
      pst = con.prepareStatement("update issuebook set IssueDate = ?, ReturnDate = ? where IssueDate is null and ReturnDate is null");
      pst.setString(1, dfd.format(now));
      pst.setString(2, dfd.format(returnvalue));
      pst.executeUpdate();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Book Issued Successfully!");
      issueLoad();
    }
    catch(SQLException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for helping me. it's really helpful for me. I am suffering with this problems from one day. thanks really :)